# How do I download TED transcripts to a Kindle Paperwhite without using Instapaper or Windows Chrome?

Tags: calibre, kindle-paperwhite, send-to-kindle, windows

I am a Windows 10 user who would occasionally like to download the entire transcript of a TED presentation to my Kindle Paperwhite *without* having to use Instapaper or Firefox's extension for Chrome (which I do not use), and without having to do any special coding.
Are there other ways? Would Calibre help in some manner? Just curious.
**Thank you!**